# Could not build module UIKIT in Xcode 6.4 and Xcode 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, xcode7, xcode6.4

I am recently open one of my old project and trying to run/build in **XCODE 6.4** and as well as **XCODE 7.0**. But showing One error that **"Could not build module 'UIKit' "**
[image]

even shows below error that **could not build module CoreImage.h** file and **coreVideo.h file not found**.

[image]
[image]

I tried following things. But unable to solve please help me.

- I removed framework and add in build setting.
- In .pch file I removed UIKIT framework and add.
- I clean derived data.
- Even check .pch file path.
- I set disable and than further enable "Use Standard Header Directory Searching".
- Even try by changing deployment target but not work for me.

Help me please.

Comment: Just a tip: This occurred when I accidentally typed something in `UICollectionView.h`, replacing it physically inside sdk folder with another fresh copy of this header from my friend's sdk solved this.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got solution, I go through target > shown in folder and here i found there is one corevideo framework and i just removed it and try to build/run app and its worked successful :)

Answer (score 0):

I did the following process to solve this problem of not finding the UIKit,

- I cleaned the devided data;
- I checked to see if any of the Foundation files had changed.

I advise you to check in the Foundation for these files, CoreImage.h and coreVideo.h to see if you do not have any changed files in your root.

Comment: Wait - so you put system framework headers into source control? That's a bad idea! Don't do that. In Xcode settings there's a checkbox somewhere to allow "Automatically unlock files" (or something along those lines). Just disable that checkbox and you're not able to change a header without a popup warning from Xcode.

Comment: This is not present in my Xcode. So to tell him to see if there was any change in the Foundation files.

Comment: It's been around for a very long time, it's right there in settings: http://imgur.com/a/ddkNv